# How to choose the initial wavefunction with path integral formulation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, path-integral

How shall you choose the initial wavefunction $\psi(x,0)$ when computing a quantum mechanical system in path integral formulation
$$\psi(x_b,t) = \int K(x_b,x_a;t) \psi(x_a,0) dx_a$$
It seems that Gaussian wavepackets are often used for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no one singular choice -- it depends on the problem at hand. A common problem in undergraduate quantum mechanics might be where you are given an initial wavefunction $\psi(x_a, 0)$ and you are asked to calculate the wavefunction at a later time. Another common problem might be to choose $\psi(x_a, 0)$ to be a particular basis wavefunction, since you can then calculate the evolution of an arbitrary wavefunction by linear superposition.

In quantum field theory, usually both the initial and final state are chosen to be the ground state, ie the vacuum. This is because the most common objects calculated in QFT, the time-ordered vacuum expectation values (which can be related to physical scattering cross sections, among other observables), are essentially the amplitudes for the creation and later destruction of particles at a collection of spacetime locations, beginning and ending in the vacuum state.